# Fetching country from IP using wordpress plugin GeoIP detection?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've installed this plugin: https://tah.wordpress.org/plugins/geoip-detect/

The plugin seems to work fine when I test "lookup" within the plugin, it returns my geo-information.
However when I try to implement code within one of my wordpress pages it doesn't work.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip($ip);
echo $userInfo->country->name;
```

I'm calling the function from a native woocommerce page where single-products are shown.
But the fucntion returns nothing.
Do I have to include anything more to call the function [geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip()](https://github.com/yellowtree/wp-geoip-detect/wiki/API-Usage-Examples)?

I also tried:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[geoip_detect2 property='country']"); ?>
```

It doesn't return anything either.
I'm doing the editing within godaddy's code editing tool, so I might be missing errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have try implement GEO by IP in my wordpress site http://iradiofind.com/stations/. I am using http://www.geoplugin.net to get the country info. To got the ip address i am using this function

```
function get_client_ip() {
     $ipaddress = '';
     if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
     else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
     else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
     else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
     else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
     else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
     else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

     return $ipaddress;
}

function ip_details($url) {
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
   $data = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);

   return $data;
}
```

And this is in my page template.

```
<?php 
    $myipd = get_client_ip(); 
    $url = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip='.$myipd; 
    $details    =   ip_details($url); 
    $v = json_decode($details);
    $mycountry = $v->geoplugin_countryName;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have recently used the same plugin for a custom solution - I noticed the plugin have an IP detection function built in - **geoip_detect2_get_client_ip()** - try to use that instead?

Edited from your code:

```
$ip = geoip_detect2_get_client_ip();
$userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip($ip);
echo $userInfo->country->name;
```

This function has cache functionality built in as well, and in my testing it seemed very fast.

Comment: Using geoip_detect2_get_info_from_ip instead geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip. Now it's working.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the *geoip-detect* functions are out of your scope *(something that would be very strange)*. Add this to your **functions.php**:

```
require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins/geoip-detect/geoip-detect.php';
```